# Websocket with Apollo Express, Nginx and docker-compose

Tags: javascript, reactjs, nginx, google-cloud-platform, graphql

I am trying to set up WebSockets in GCP with `graphql` subscriptions and `Nginx` but, it is not working as i am getting an issue with the `Nginx` config.

```
server {
    listen 80;
    root web-react/build;
    index index.html;

    location / {
        try_files $uri /index.html;

    }

    location ^~/graphql {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:4000/graphql;
    }
   
    location /websocket{
    proxy_pass http://graphql;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you provide more details like the error you are facing while deploying Websocket and the yaml file of docker compose to narrow down the issue.

Comment: actually that configuration worked but the websocket is disconnecting frequently for every one minute so, subscriptions are not working

Comment: I have found a [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63177824/secure-websocket-with-apollo-express-nginx-and-docker-compose) related to WebSockets subscription issue which can help you.